# JavaFX runAsync with progress indicator and runLater

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

My code is loading connections asynchronously:

```
runAsync {
    controller.loadConnections(viewModel)
} ui {
    table.items = it
    table.refresh()
}
```

and inside `loadConnections` method:

```
//read connections from file and then 
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    CollectionsKt.bind(connections, databases, ConnectionsModel::new);
    connections.forEach(connection -> connection.setOwner(viewModel));
});
```

When I want to add progress bar as:

```
private val status = TaskStatus()
runAsync(status) {
    controller.loadConnections(viewModel)
} ui {
    table.items = it
    table.refresh()
}
```

But it blocks the progress indicator. As I understand 2 tasks (`progress` and `Platform.runLater`) are not executed in `async`. But how do I get this to work?

Comment: not directly related (and not overly familiar with tornadofx, just assuming table.refresh is the same as in plain javafx): don't use it - seemingly being needed might be an indication of incorrect wiring of data/view

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    for (int n = 1; n > size; n++)
        progressBar.setProgress(n);
});
```